# Adjust size in virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

I have just installed two virtual machines by virtualbox. Somehow I get one virtual box window like this (and this is what I want):

[image]

but I don't know how to get this mode in other (I switched to 'Adjust window size' mode but It had not scroll bar like above one).

[image]

So how can I do to get screen mode like the first one (have full size window)

thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install guest additions.

1. Press Host (usually right Ctrl) + D and you will see a mounted disk.
2. Run it and it will install the guest additions.
3. Reboot the virtual machine and you're good to go. :)

If Host + D doesn't work, click on the Devices option of your virtualbox and you will see "Install Guest Additions" option at the bottom of the drop-down menu.

Comment: I installed it, but nothing change. In the first system, It is also not installed "Guest Additions" but it look good (fullscreen)

Comment: I'm confused. did you install it and nothing changed or were you not able to install it? If you installed the guest additions, you need to reboot the VBox and the changes will take effect.